# Python 2.7 encoding from csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a problem with Python 2.7 encoding I have a csv file with some french characters (mangé, parlé, prêtre ...), the code I'm using is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
path_dataset = 'P:\\Version_python\\Dataset\\data_set - Copy.csv'
dataset = pd.read_csv(path_dataset, sep=';')

for lab, row in dataset.iterrows():
    print(row['Summary'])
```

I tried to add `encoding` to `read_csv()`, it didn't work. I tried `unicode`, `decode`(UTF-8) ... Nothing worked.

Then I tried to concatenate those extracted words with some text, and I got a utf-8 error, I don't know how to deal with that. Thanks

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: Add above line at the start of python file and try

Comment: what exact error you are facing ? could you paste that ?

Comment: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 39: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of standard python encodings

[Standard Python 2.7 encodings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html)

`utf-8` does not work but you can try some other encodings on the link above.

Just tested `latin_1` works. So the code should be:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(path_dataset, sep=';', encoding='latin_1')
```

Comment: yep, i think OP just has to find the correct encoding for his CSV file...

Comment: Ok, actually I think I found my problem, latin_1 is working fine, but later in my code I use this:    df_content_mail = df_content_mail.replace('/', ' ')
which send an error 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @geilelou Not sure if `ascii` will work though. I tested your words with `read_csv` and `ascii` did not work for me

Comment: I found one solution, it is to use re.sub(), df.replace() doesn't deal well with latin_1

Answer (score 0):

You can use codecs in python2.7

```
import codecs
file = codecs.open(filename, encoding="utf-8")
```